# ¡Introduzca una Longitud Valida!

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hola Necesito crear eta tabla en phpMyAdmin pero no puedo avanzar ya que me lanza este error al guardar esta es la estructura SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` ( `id_ticket` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `nombre_usuario` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `no_asociado` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
 `planta` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `departamento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 `reporte` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `estatus` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 `fecha_solicitud` DATETIME NOT NULL , `fecha_finalizado` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_ticket`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: sera por el int(10)???

Comment: que longitud debería de ser?

Comment: ninguno? int ya sabe los valores que puede contener...

Comment: Yo nisiquiera puedo obtener el error que mencionas. Cree una base de datos `test` a la cual le inserte ese SQL, y obtuve resultado positivo. https://i.gyazo.com/4351a14779142ea5763d3cb7aed22191.png

Comment: es raro, por que efectivamente ejecute la instrucción SQL desde comando y no dio error, lo extraño es que en modo visual no me dejaba avanzar, solo marcaba ese error, de todos modos GRACIAS por su asistencia.

Comment: Al poner INT en vez de INT(10), el error desaparece ?

Answer (score 2):

Resumiendo: el problema lo tienes en INT(10) que debería ser simplemente INT.

Si bien los tipos de datos `VARCHAR` se definen por la longitud de caracteres máximos que pueden albergar, el tipo `INT`, genéricamente tipo entero, se mide en bytes y su longitud no se define en el tipo, sino que cada longitud tiene su propio tipo.

Los rangos de datos que pueden tomar para enteros con signo son:

```
Tipo         Valor mínimo     Valor máximo
TINYINT          -128               255
SMALLINT       -32768             32767
MEDIUMINT    -8388608           8388608
INT       -2147483648        2147483647
BIGINT        -2^63             2^63
```

En [este documento](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) tienes más información